# What's the best way to get terminal commands explained?

Tags: shell, command, command-line-arguments

Based on a terminal command I have (bash, sh, whatever), I would like to get some details about what every argument does. What's the best option out there to achieve exactly this?

I remember I saw a web app that does just this, but I cannot recall its name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a great app that does just this: [explainshell.com](http://explainshell.com)

Answer (score 0):

in linux:

```
man command
```

in windows:

```
command help
```

or

```
command /?
```

Comment: This works for a single command. I would like to type, for example, `ls -l | grep ".html"` and get the whole command explained, piece by piece.